# Keep getting jfindClass(as.character(driverClass)[1]) error

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, shiny-server, rjava, amazon-athena

I'm trying to run this script on my R Shiny Server, but I've been tripped up on this one error for hours now.

My script, at least the part causing the error, is as such:

```
library(rJava)
library(RJDBC)
library(RPostgreSQL)

URL <- 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/athena-downloads/drivers/JDBC/SimbaAthenaJDBC_2.0.2/AthenaJDBC42_2.0.2.jar'
fil <- basename(URL)
if (!file.exists(fil)) download.file(URL, fil)

drv <- JDBC(driverClass="com.amazonaws.athena.jdbc.AthenaDriver", fil, identifier.quote="'")
```

When I run it, the error it returns is as follows:

```
Loading required package: methods
Loading required package: DBI
Error in .jfindClass(as.character(driverClass)[1]) : class not found
Calls: JDBC -> is.jnull -> .jfindClass
Execution halted
```

I've tried a lot of different things today, too many to count, and I always get that same error.

The weirdest thing is, when I run it on my local RStudio, it works totally fine. It's just when I get it on the server it starts bugging out.

Can someone please help? I've been stuck on this for awhile now and any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: maybe the jre version on your local PC and server is diff?

Comment: What is the output of - sudo R CMD javareconf ?

Comment: @ReshamWadhwa Since I don't have enough characters to paste the whole thing, [here is a screenshot!](https://imgur.com/a/4dSkjM2)

Comment: And you're getting the same error after running this command ?

Comment: @wizkids121 after running javareconf , you're still getting the same error ?

Comment: I've had the same issue. Unfortunately, javareconf looks to be a bash script? I'm running on a Windows box, so I can use it. Any equivalent for Windows env?